# How to embed playlist in youtube API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I know how to embed a youtube video with a playlist and it's all fine. Except I don't get events. I need to know when the video or playlist is over. I know how to use [the youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to load in a video and get the stop event. I don't know how to get them both together.

Here is an example to test with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlUKcNNmywk&list=PLE5FFF0C74122C403. I tried [queue playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playlist_Queueing_Functions) and looking at the other commands. It appears I can create a playlist dynamically. I don't know how to get a list of videos in an already existing playlist. My goal is having someone drop in a video id + playlist id and find out when the video/playlist is over.

Comment: [Retrieve your playlist information](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Retrieving_playlist_information) and check if it's the last video of the playlist. If it is, then check for `YT.PlayerState.ENDED`.

Comment: I end up figuring it out. A few thing that wasn't intuitive was 1) I couldn't use the list in the create object when I specified video. 2) I had to wait for the player load event before I could call a function 3) The using argument for loadPlaylist gave me an error where using the object form didn't (WTF?). Maybe I'm a noob with YT/Google/Web API but IMO their document isn't very good

Comment: @Andy: I forgot to @ you. After all of that I was able to retrieve the playlist as you suggested. Also a working example would have helped. Mozilla and MS have plenty all over their documentation (at least the .NET part of msdn). Working examples would have made this so simple